# Need some help simplifying a script in bash

Tags: bash

this is my first post actually.
appreciated anyone who can help.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *
 do
  if [ -s $file ]; then
        continue
   else
        echo "$file is empty and will be removed"
        rm $file
  fi
 done
     for file in *
      do
       if [ -x $file -a -f $file ];then
          echo "$file is an executable"
       fi
      done
```

Is there a more simple way to write this script so its all in 1 for loop?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *; do
  if [ -s "$file" ]; then 
      if [ -x "$file" -a -f "$file" ]; then
          echo "$file" "is an executable"
      fi
  else 
      echo "$file" "is empty and will be removed"
      rm "$file" 
  fi

done
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell; Oops! Thanks. Corrected now.

Comment: @haccks: It would be a good idea to quote the variables to avoid getting the file-names undergo Word-splitting. Even if they don't have a space, it is a good practice to recommend, or use the extended `test` operator

Comment: @Inian; Agreed. I usually use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` and do not quote variables in that case but quoting is always good.